# Tumblr: replace automatically "_540.jpg" images with "_1280.jpg" images

Tags: javascript, html, size, tumblr, tumblr-themes

When I upload photos to a Tumblr text post, it automatically uses the 540px resized version of that photos (notice the "**_540.jpg**" at the end of the url)

```
<img data-orig-height="675" data-orig-width="1200" alt="image" src="https://41.media.tumblr.com/08f28bf8ea1ee458a8d62dc7238f23a7/tumblr_inline_ntx4f3leGy1s7wjfw_540.jpg">
```

I can edit the HTML of the post and change the "_540" with "_1280" to make it use the 1280px version of that image (and also remove some things to make it work properly and look like this):

```
<img src="https://41.media.tumblr.com/08f28bf8ea1ee458a8d62dc7238f23a7/tumblr_inline_ntx4f3leGy1s7wjfw_1280.jpg">
```

But making this change manually, on each image, on each post is really annoying. So I would like to do this automatically. Is it possible to include something in the code to do this job?

I know this is not an easy question. Thank you.

Comment: set img height and width

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the bottom of your page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $('img').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('_540.','_1280.'));
        });
    }(jQuery));
    </script>
```